# Django Upload Image to AWS S3 Not Working After Upgrade to Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I have (finally) upgraded to Django 1.10 from Django 1.8 and while there has been some obvious challenges, the only struggle is my image upload to S3. While upgrading Django, I was also forced to upgrade Boto & PIL.

While the original image will still correctly upload to the requested bucket (originals), however, the save function that would create a thumb and would save it to another bucket no longer works.

Here is my code that was working correctly until the Django/Boto/PIL upgrade:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.create_avatar_thumb()

def create_avatar_thumb(self):
    import os
    from PIL import Image
    from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage

    if not self.filename:
        return ""
    file_path = self.filename.name

    filename_base, filename_ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    original_file_path = "%s%s" % (filename_base, filename_ext)

    xm_file_path = original_file_path.replace('originals/', 'xm/')

    if storage.exists(xm_file_path):
        return "exists"

    # resize the original image to xs
    f = storage.open(file_path, 'r')
    image = Image.open(f)
    print image # example 1

    xm_size = 40, 40
    image.thumbnail(xm_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    f_thumb = storage.open(xm_file_path, "w")
    print f_thumb # example 2

    image.save(f_thumb, quality=100) 
    f_thumb.close()
```

---

**My testing:**

I get no errors running this script.

Two observations: When I run `print`, the *#example 1* would print twice and the `print` on *#example 2* is empty

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with Pillow's `.save()` method using s3 so I went through a StringIO before saving.

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage
from cStringIO import StringIO #for python2, you'd use "from io..." in python3

# let's say we have a PIL image called 'Image'
sfile = StringIO()
Image.save(sfile, format="png") # save a png to the StringIO
with storage.open('somepath/somefile.png', 'w+') as f:
  f.write(sfile.getvalue())
```

I'm on Django 1.9. I have no idea why this broke on your upgrade, but this is what has worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will definitely give it a try. Actually, pillow 4.0 is working OK with Django 1.8. There has been some changes in django-storages between version 1.1.8 and 1.2.0. because the upload no longer works in Django 1.8 when I use anything newer than django-storages 1.8.. When I use django-storages 1.8 with django 1.10, I get `get_available_name() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length'` error which I'm unable to overwrite as it is inside the django-storages package.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy S. answer worked for me, except I needed to use BytesIO():
from io import BytesIO.  This was using django 1.11 with python3 and s3Boto3 storages on AWS.